# WP_Query не работает на простых страницах с пользовательскими таксономиями

Tags: wordpress

Перепробовал много функций wp и большинство не работает например в том же `functions.php` c произвольными таксаномиями, хотя на страницах записей все нормально работает

Пример запроса:

```
$mypost = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category_advert',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'avtorynok'
      ),
)); 

$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
```

Кто знает в чем может быть причина? А то надоело уже в ручною запросы к бд делать.

Таксономии через плагин tooset создавались

Comment: В functions.php? Вы используете выборку раньше, чем регистрируете таксономию)

Comment: так. а как правильно мне тогда подключать пользовательские функции, через хук чтоль? Если описать задачу полностью. То мне нужно при сохранение пользовательских полей в  таксаномии (хук carbon_fields_term_meta_container_saved) нужно обновить данные таксаномий в таблице бд но пока застопорился на том что не могу получить все записи каторые относятся к определенному термину пользовательской таксаномии

Comment: Этот файл я подключал в function но по вашим словам это не правильно. что логично. Потому что он в самом начале грузится. но что делать то?))))

Comment: я по вешал подключение подобных функций на wp_loaded. но хотелось бы узнать мнение специалиста. может есть более изящное решение. но стрелку нажал. спасибо за совет

Comment: я не знаю как работает плагин для регистрации таксономии) Попробуйте через register_taxonomy на init зарегистрировать таксономию)